# Warnin de sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, sql-server

voy al grano, estoy haciendo un buscador y al poner ciertos nombres o datos, se muestras los resultados, el problema es con algunos otros donde no se muestra nada y me muestra el siguiente warning

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in

y aun no se como se resuelve el error, les paso la parte donde me marca esta el error.

Aquí mi código:

```
<?php
//USAR dicc.php para cambiar usuario pass y DB
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
function dd($attr){
    print_r($attr);
    echo "-----<br>";
    var_dump($attr);
    echo "-----<br>";
    echo serialize($attr);
    die();
}
$logFile = "querys.log";
function creaWhere($attr, $cols){
    $tmp = ""; // variable temporal para sacar los wheres de la query
    if (count($attr) != 0) {
        foreach ($attr as $val) {
            $tmp .= " (";
            foreach ($cols as $col) {
                $tmp .= ($col === end($cols))? $col." LIKE "."'%".$val."%'" : $col." LIKE "."'%".$val."%' OR ";
            }
            $tmp .= ($val === end($attr))? ")" : ") AND";
        }
        return $tmp;
    }else{ return "1";} //regresa 1 para mostrar todos los datos de la tabla
}
include "dicc.php";
//variables POST
$serch = utf8_encode($_POST['search']);
$table = $_POST['table'];
$idx = isset($_GET['idx']) ? $_GET['idx'] : 1;
//--------------
$indexOffset = $idx != 0 ? ($idx - 1) * 10 : 0;
$attr = explode(' ', $serch); //agregamos cada palabra del search a una entrada de attr
$serverName = SVR; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>DBO, "UID"=>USR, "PWD"=>PSS, "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
    //-------------------------------
$where = creaWhere($attr, $COLUMNS[$DBOS[$table]]); //le metemos los atributos de busqueda y las columnas en las que debe de buscar a la funcion
$queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$DBOS[$table]." where $where" ;
$start = microtime(true);
$count = sqlsrv_fetch_array(sqlsrv_query($conn, $queryCount))[0];
file_put_contents($logFile, $queryCount."\n TOTAL de resultados: ".$count);    
if ($count == 0) { //checa si hay resultados
    $hay = 0;
}else {
    //crea la query que devolvera las columnas indicadas en el diccionario en el array SELECTS, se crea despues de confirmar que hay resultados con la primera query
    $fetch = ($count - $indexOffset) > 10 ? "FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY" : "";
    $query = "SELECT ". 
             implode(", ", $SELECTS[$DBOS[$table]]) . 
             " FROM ".$DBOS[$table]." WHERE ". $where . 
             " ORDER BY ". $COLUMNS[$DBOS[$table]][0] ." ASC".
             ($count <= 10 ? "" : " OFFSET $indexOffset ROWS $fetch");
    file_put_contents($logFile, "\n".$query, FILE_APPEND);
    $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query); //ejecuta la query
    $hay = 1;
    // si hay resultados extrae los headers de las columnas para despues ponerlo en la tabla html
    $end = microtime(true) - $start;
    file_put_contents($logFile, "\n tiempo de ejecución TOTAL: ".$end, FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents("time-data.txt", count($attr)." ".$end."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Y aquí es donde marca el error exactamente en la linea del while

```
//imprime resultados codificados a utf8 en caso de no haber resultados no hace nada
                if($hay){
                    $i = 0;
                    while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        if ($i == 0) {
                            $headers = array_keys($result);
                            echo "<thead><tr>";
                                foreach ($headers as $head) {
                                    echo "<th> $head </th>";
                                }
                            echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";
                        }
                        $i+=1;
                        echo "<tr>";
                            foreach ($result as $col) {
                                if($col instanceof DateTime){
                                    $txt = $col->format('Y-m-d');
                                }
                                else{
                                    $txt=(string)$col; 
                                }
                                echo "<td>". utf8_encode($txt) ."</td>";
                                //echo $col;
                                //echo $col->format("Y-m-d");
                            }
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                }
```

Eso es todo, si se necesita más código puedo ponerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leyendo la documentación de [sqlsrv_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php).

**Signatura**

```
array sqlsrv_fetch_array ( resource $stmt [, int $fetchType [, int $row [, int $offset ]]] )
```

**Parámetro resource $stmt**

> stmt
>
> Un recurso de sentencia devuelta por sqlsrv_query o sqlsrv_prepare.

Mirando tu código `$results` se obtiene como resultado de una llamada a `sqlsrv_query`.

Mirando la documentación de [sqlsrv_query](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-query.php).

**Signatura**

```
mixed sqlsrv_query ( resource $conn , string $sql [, array $params [, array $options ]] )
```

Devuelve algo tipo `mixed`, quiere decir que puede devolver distintos tipos.

Siguiendo puede leerse:

> Valores devueltos
>
> Returns a statement resource on success and FALSE if an error occurred.

Es decir, que si hubo un erro devuelve `FALSE`, es decir un tipo booleano. Tal como indica el warning.

Por ese lado, misterio resuelto.

Viendo el ejemplo de la documentación, lo primero que hace es verificar el tipo devuelto.

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Por lo que mi sugerencia, sería modificar tu código acorde para tener esto en cuenta. Por ejemplo:

```
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query); //ejecuta la query
if( $results === false ) {
    $hay= 0;
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
    }
    //Codigo necesario para terminar la ejecución con gracia
}
```

Comment: Lo siento he estado en otros proyectos que deje esto unos días, ya hice lo sugerido y arroja lo siguiet: `SQLSTATE: 42000
code: 102
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'OFFSET'.
SQLSTATE: 42000
code: 153
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Uso no válido de la opción NEXT en la instrucción FETCH.`  
Lo cual no compredo bien si a mi parecer todo esta bien definido!

Comment: Habría que entender la consulta que estás ejecutando. Te sugiero que agregues el valor de $query a tu pregunta para el caso en que falla la consulta.

Comment: Hice varias pruebas y al final resultó lo que hacia ruido era esta parte `($count <= 10 ? "" : " OFFSET $indexOffset ROWS $fetch");` cuando quito el "<" salen los resultados; estoy pensando que puede ser por la versión de sql server, ya que en otra maquina con una versión 2016 no hay problema alguno, más en ésta 2012, no se porque no saca el resultado esperado! Alguna otra sugerencia? Por cierto gracias me ha servido mucho tus respuestas :)

Answer (score 0):

me parece que el error se produce cuando no hay resultados para la busqueda o tienes algun error en la consulta.. prueba mirando cuantos resultados te trae el query.

al ejecutar el query haz algo como;

```
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query); //ejecuta la query
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $results );
if($row_count>0){
  $hay = true;
}else{
  die("No hay resultados a mostrar");
}
```

Saludos espero te sea de de ayuda.

EDITO

---

Se me ocurre que uses algo como esto:

```
if($hay){
   $i = 0;
    if($results)
        while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {


        if ($i == 0) {
                        $headers = array_keys($result);
                        echo "<thead><tr>";
                            foreach ($headers as $head) {
                                echo "<th> $head </th>";
                            }
                        echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";
                    }
                    $i+=1;
                    echo "<tr>";
                        foreach ($result as $col) {
                            if($col instanceof DateTime){
                                $txt = $col->format('Y-m-d');
                            }
                            else{
                                $txt=(string)$col; 
                            }
                            echo "<td>". utf8_encode($txt) ."</td>";
                            //echo $col;
                            //echo $col->format("Y-m-d");
                        }
                    echo "</tr>";
    }
    else{
        if(($errors = sqlsrv_errors()) != null) {
            foreach( $errors as $error ) {
                echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
                echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
                echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Bien, también pensé en eso y para saber si hay resultados cree un log, donde me dice cuántos resultados hubo y el tiempo que se tardó en buscar, por ejemplo, busqué "Diana Aurora" y aunque arroja el Warning, me dice el log que hubo 37 resultados

Comment: Prueba metiendo la query en el log y ejecutandola directamente en el servidor SQL y ver si da error o algun problema...

Comment: Ya, y no me da ningun error, se ejecuta bien y me da los 37 resultados, parece ser que es otra cosa el problema

Comment: Ambos fragmentos de codigo estan en el mismo archivo?

Comment: Ok lo que el log me genera es un count con los parametros a buscar y un select, ese select es el que meto a sql y me da los resultados, es el mismo select que se genera en el php se guarda en el log para ver si hay resultados y el tiempo que tarda en buscar

Comment: Puedes poner un poco mas de codigo? lo que esté antes del if($hay){....

Comment: Ya lo agregué arriba, en mi pregunta :)

Comment: Bien, seguido a ese codigo esta el del fraagmento inferior, correcto?  que comienza con if($hay){...

Comment: Así es, después viene html el cual omito porque solo creo unos div y sigue el while donde me marca el warning

Comment: el resultado de 
    $query = "SELECT ". 
             implode(", ", $SELECTS[$DBOS[$table]]) . 
             " FROM ".$DBOS[$table]." WHERE ". $where . 
             " ORDER BY ". $COLUMNS[$DBOS[$table]][0] ." ASC".
             ($count <= 10 ? "" : " OFFSET $indexOffset ROWS $fetch");
cual es?

Comment: Aquí un ejemplo de una busqueda con "Lourdes"

Comment: `SELECT NOMBRE as 'Nombres', PATERNO as 'Apellido Paterno', MATERNO as 'Apellido Materno', FECHANAC as 'Fecha de Nacimiento', MUNICIPIO as 'Municipio', JUZGADO as 'Juzgado', ANO as 'AA', LIBRO as 'Libro', ACTA as 'Acta', OBSERVAC as 'Observacion' FROM NACIMEXT WHERE  (NOMBRE LIKE '%Lourdes%' OR PATERNO LIKE '%Lourdes%' OR MATERNO LIKE '%Lourdes%' OR CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), FECHANAC, 126) LIKE '%Lourdes%' OR ACTA LIKE '%Lourdes%' OR LIBRO LIKE '%Lourdes%' OR ANO LIKE '%Lourdes%' OR MUNICIPIO LIKE '%Lourdes%' OR JUZGADO LIKE '%Lourdes%') ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`

Comment: Me parece extraño que tengas 37 resultados con un  OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY

Comment: Si, es que para ese select se usa para saber el tiempo de ejecución, realmente los resultados para esa consulta son:  18318

Comment: Entiendo, lo que se me ocurre es condicionar ese warning.. te dejo en mi respuesta com se haría para ver si existe un error o algo.

Comment: Lo siento he estado en otro proyecto que ya no puse atención a esto por una semana, el resultado que arroja es el siguiente: `SQLSTATE: 42000
code: 102
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'OFFSET'.
SQLSTATE: 42000
code: 153
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Uso no válido de la opción NEXT en la instrucción FETCH.`